# Array keys starting with characters

Tags: php

I have an array with terms and definitions:

```
$myArray = array("apple" => "Fruit that grows ...", "car" => "Vehicle on four...");
```

How do I determine if I have words starting with a particular letter in $myArray, say, "c" for car and add a class to corresponding letter in my ABC list that is generated via a loop:

```
foreach(range('A','Z') as $i) {
    echo '<div>'. $i .'</div>';
}
```

UPDATE:

Expected output:

```
<div class="match">A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div class="match">C</div>
```

Comment: What would your expected output look like ...

Comment: Great idea, @Baba, I should've thought of it...

Comment: Edited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: So many answers already  ... let me know if you need anything different

Comment: Are you searching for `a to z` or `A to Z` or `both`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare whether the character you are about to output does exist as a first character in the array keys. Compared with all the other working solutions, which iterate over the whole data array over and over again, using a little preparation should make it easier and more understandable what happens.

```
$myArray = array("apple" => "Fruit that grows ...", "car" => "Vehicle on four...", "cat" => "Meow");

// Prepare array keys
$keys = array_keys($myArray);
array_walk($keys, function(&$key){$key=mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($key,0,1));});
array_unique($keys);

foreach (range('A','Z') as $char) {
    if (in_array($char, $keys)) {
        echo "<div class='match'>".$char."</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div>".$char."</div>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<div class='match'>A</div><div>B</div><div class='match'>C</div><div>D</div><div>E</div><div>F</div> ...
```

Comment: He wanted the keys that begin with each letter, not just c.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin that cat. Here's one:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/^[A-Z]/', array_keys($myArray));
foreach($matches as $i) {
    echo '<div>'. $i .'</div>';
}
```

That one's case sensitive. To match A-Z and a-z, add the *i* modifier to the regex.

Comment: I like cats... This one, it seems, will only output only the letters that have matches. I need them all, just add class to matched. ;)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question. Now that you've updated it, this doesn't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('a' => 'dog', 'b' => 'cat');
// For each letter from A to Z, contained in $i
foreach (range('A','Z') as $i) {
    echo '<b>' . $i . '</b><br />'; // Output the letter

    // For each key/value pair of the array
    foreach ($myArray as $key => $element) {
        // If the first letter of the key is the letter, it matches
        // This matches both upper and lowercase
        if (in_array($key[0], array($i, strtolower($i)))) {
            echo '<div class="match">' . $element . '</div><br />';
        }
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

That loops through A - Z and checks each key/value pair to see if the key begins with that letter (or its lowercase counterpart; it checks both A and a).

EDIT: **Updated based on update to question**

Comment: I am aware of that. Try the following code. It works: `$foo = 'bar'; echo $foo[1]; // output: a`

Comment: To clarify, individual characters in a string can be accessed by supplying the index (beginning at 0) of that character in the string. So in the example I just provided, a is the second character in the string 'bar', but is at position (index) 1.

Comment: Works only as long as you are in single-byte-world aka ASCII.

Comment: So do you not want to add the class where the key is B? Then doing a range will not work, as B is included in the range.

Comment: @Sven well he asked for A-Z, so I gave him A-Z.

Comment: @santa okay, I updated the script. that should get you started, you can adapt it from there; we're not here to write your code for you :P

Comment: @santa: Good point. :) With `$myArray = array("apple" => "Fruit that grows ...", "car" => "Vehicle on four...", "cat" => "Meow");` I get following output: `<div class="match">A</div>AABBBC<div class="match">C</div><div class="match">C</div>DDDEEEFFFGGGHHHIIIJJJKKKLLLMMMNNNOOOPPPQQQRRRSSSTTTUUUVVVWWWXXXYYYZZZ`

Comment: @santa You would unconditionally output the $i in the first foreach. Then, inside the if() you would echo $element instead of $i. Of course add a line break for better readability

Comment: Although, running the script, that outputs every array element for each letter. If you remove the else part of the if() statement, that only outputs the element in a match. I'm not sure if that's what you want, but like I said, you're welcome to adapt it further to meet your needs.

Comment: @imkingdavid: You still have a syntax error, missing closing parenthesis after the if. And it still does not work. Are you actually running the code you are using? Try executing first.

Comment: Well yes, I noticed the syntax error and it is fixed. The updated code in the answer works. to print each letter with any keys that begin with that letter. Regardless, he accepted your answer so I'm not going to waste any more time on this. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$arr = array("apple" => "Fruit that grows ...", "car" => "Vehicle on four...");   
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
 foreach(range('a','z') as $i ) {
 if (strpos($k, $i) === 0) 
  echo "<div class='match'>". $i .'</div>';
 else
   echo '<div>'. $i .'</div>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Output: `<div class='match'>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>e</div>
<div>f</div>
<div>g</div>
<div>h</div>
<div>i</div>
<div>j</div>
<div>k</div>
<div>l</div>
<div>m</div>
<div>n</div>
<div>o</div>
<div>p</div>
<div>q</div>
<div>r</div>
<div>s</div>
<div>t</div>
<div>u</div>
<div>v</div>
<div>w</div>
<div>x</div>
<div>y</div>
<div>z</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div class='match'>c</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>e</div>
<div>f</div>
<div>g</div>
<div>h</div>
<div>i</div>...`